# VB.NET must implement error

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I just convert the C# function to VB.NET function but somehow I get some error. Below is my C# function.

```
public abstract class BaseFilterControl: UserControl,IFilterControl
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public FilterDescriptorBase AssociatedDescriptor { get; set; }

    public bool IsFirst { get; set; }

    public abstract FilterDescriptorBase BuildDescriptor();

    protected abstract void Initialize();
}
```

Below is my current VB function

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseFilterControl
    Inherits UserControl
    Implements IFilterControl

    Public Property PropertyName As String

    Public Property AssociatedDescriptor As FilterDescriptorBase

    Public Property IsFirst As Boolean

    Public MustOverride Function BuildDescriptor() As FilterDescriptorBase

    Protected MustOverride Sub Initialize()
End Class
```

I got this error:

```
BaseFilterControl must implement Function BuildDescriptor() As FilterDescriptorBase.
```

Any idea. Please help. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need an implementation of BuildDescriptor(), rather than an abstract method.

Comment: @emodendroket Why, if it's abstract/MustOverride?

Comment: @emodendroket. How should I do it ?

Comment: @emodendroket: An abstract method implementing an interface method is just fine - all it needs is the "Implements" clause on the method.

Comment: Well, good thing I made that a comment instead of an answer then.

Answer (score 5):

An abstract method implementing an interface method in fine. In VB, you just need to specify that the function implements the interface function:

```
Public MustOverride Function BuildDescriptor() As FilterDescriptorBase Implements IFilterControl.BuildDescriptor
```

You might need to add more "Implements" clauses for other methods - I'm not familiar with the IFilterControl interface.